# How to manage messages to different users in telegram using telethon?

Tags: api, bots, telegram, telethon

I am working with telethon API and created a survey bot. A survey is a sequence of custom polls(A message string and a list of buttons) that is sent to the private users/or chats on telegram. A single poll is sent from a sequence to the user and bot waits for that user to reply and then the next poll in the sequence is sent to that user. It's working fine. But the problem is when there are multiple users taking a survey at the same time how can I keep track of each user's poll number its survey and which message was sent previously to that user so I may know which message/poll the bot will send next to individual users. I am new to stackoverflow.com and development. Thanks!

Comment: You need to keep track of several things: what the poll is, who sent it, which chat did it send it to, and which is the message ID of the poll. You probably want to persist this information to disk, using something like JSON, pickle or a database.

Comment: Thanks for reply. But already figured that I should use shove/shelf module. But thanks again for reaching out.